# On a Falcon9 launch at T-13 they poll all stations, what are all the stations they poll?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, launch-sequence

While listening to the webcast for flight 8 of Falcon 9 (Thiacom-8 mission), they did a poll of all controllers/stations at T-13:00.

I could guess a number of them, but wondering what the full set is.

I caught

- FTS  Flight Termination System
- MM  Mission Manager
- GNC  Guidance and Navigation Control
- GC Ground Control
- VC ??
- CE  ??
- OSM ??

What were the rest, and what do they stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those acronyms in your list that are missing an explanation:

```
CE    -   Chief Engineer
OSM   -   Operations Safety Manager
VC    -   Vehicle Control
```

And some other acronyms of the SpaceX parlance, in alphabetical order (repeating top ones):

```
AVI   -   Avionics Operator
CE    -   Chief Engineer
CC    -   Control Center
CFR   -   Code of Federal Regulations
FRC   -   Falcon Recovery Coordinator
FTS   -   Flight Termination System
FS    -   Flight Software
FSPO  -   Flight Safety Project Officer
GC    -   Ground Control
GNC   -   Guidance, Navigation, & Control
GS    -   Ground Station
GSO   -   Ground Safety Officer
LAM   -   Launch Area Manager 
LC    -   Launch Control
LD    -   Launch Director
LDA   -   Launch Decision Authority
LPM   -   Launch Pad Manager
MCC   -   Mission Control Center
MCC-X -   SpaceX Mission Control Center in Hawthorne, CA
MECO  -   Main Engine Cut Off
MM    -   Mission Manager
OD    -   Orbital Director
OSM   -   Operations Safety Manager
OSS   -   Operational Safety Supervisor
PAO   -   Public Affairs Office
PLDA  -   Pre-Launch Danger Area
POC   -   Point of Contact 
Prop  -   Propulsion
RC    -   Range Coordinator
RCO   -   Range Control Officer
RMMO  -   Range and Mission Management Office 
ROC   -   Range Operations Coordinator
RSO   -   Range Safety Officer
SE    -   Systems Engineer
SECO  -   Second Stage Engine Cut Off
SSO   -   Site Safety Officer
TVC   -   Thrust Vector Control
VC    -   Vehicle Control
```

Most of these are taken from [reddit /r/SpaceX, compiled by *retiringonmars*](http://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/1rns03/rspacex_falcon_9_v11_ses8_official_launch/cdp2as3), with some additions by me.

The station polling on T-13 minutes for the latest SpaceX launch of Falcon 9 deploying Thaicom 6 satellite on January 6, 2014 went as follows (transcription from the recorded launch video, in the polling order):

```
FTS    -   Flight Termination System
Prop   -   Propulsion
AVI    -   Avionics Operator
GNC    -   Guidance, Navigation, & Control
Ground -   Ground Safety Officer (GSO)
VC     -   Vehicle Control
GC     -   Ground Control
RC     -   Range Coordinator
CC     -   Control Center
OSM    -   Operations Safety Manager
ROC    -   Range Operations Coordinator
MM     -   Mission Manager
CE     -   Chief Engineer
LD     -   Launch Director (gives go-no-go to LC for terminal count)
LC     -   Launch Control (resumes countdown)
```